# XML Parser issue in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8

I am working on XML parser, at same time i am fetching multiple urls data from server.
So in iOS 6,and iOS 7 its working fine, but in iOS 8 the parser is blocked.
Please check out the screenshot.

I am using the **dispatch_queue_t** (app.forgroundQueue).

[image]

**Check the code here**

```
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
            app.isSerialQueueRunning =YES;
            dispatch_async( app.forgroundQueue, ^{
            [self setDelegate:aDelegate];
            self.responseArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
            NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                    completionHandler:
                                          ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (!error)
                                                  {
                                                   }
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                          if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ConnectionMessage:)])
                                                          {
                                                                  [_delegate ConnectionMessage:@"Parsing Fail Please Check internet Connection or Refresh Again"];
                                                          }
                                                  }

                                                  NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
                                                  [parser setDelegate:self];
                                                  [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
                                                  [parser parse];
                                                  self.allocate=@"NO";

                                          }];
            [task resume];

                    });
```

Comment: Paste code here, it will be helpful for others to test your code??

Comment: yes, update the question with code

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, try making sure the `parse` message is sent on the main queue:

```
// Start on main thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [parser parse];
});
```

Comment: but already i am create a new dispatch_queue_t and add the code in it.
dispatch_async( app.forgroundQueue, ^{
   //  Parser code
});

Comment: again same issue EXE_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Have you checked what the `data` actually contains?

Comment: any one have idea, why happen this ??